# Как убрать отступ при скроллинге?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Проблема в "header". Из-за position fixed у "sidebar", при скроллинге остается отступ:

https://jsfiddle.net/z6g97tt9/

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #fff;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 10px;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.sidebar {
  width: 140px;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;
  background: pink;
  padding: 10px;
}

.content {
  width: calc(100% - 140px);
  min-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 140px;
  background: blue;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">HEADER</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="sidebar">SIDEBAR</div>
  <div class="content">
    Lorem Ipsum - это текст-"рыба", часто используемый в печати и вэб-дизайне. Lorem Ipsum является стандартной "рыбой" для текстов на латинице с начала XVI века. В то время некий безымянный печатник создал большую коллекцию размеров и форм шрифтов, используя Lorem Ipsum для распечатки образцов. Lorem Ipsum не только успешно пережил без заметных изменений пять веков, но и перешагнул в электронный дизайн. Его популяризации в новое время послужили публикация листов Letraset с образцами Lorem Ipsum в 60-х годах и, в более недавнее время, программы электронной вёрстки типа Aldus PageMaker, в шаблонах которых используется Lorem Ipsum.
    Lorem Ipsum - это текст-"рыба", часто используемый в печати и вэб-дизайне. Lorem Ipsum является стандартной "рыбой" для текстов на латинице с начала XVI века. В то время некий безымянный печатник создал большую коллекцию размеров и форм шрифтов, используя Lorem Ipsum для распечатки образцов. Lorem Ipsum не только успешно пережил без заметных изменений пять веков, но и перешагнул в электронный дизайн. Его популяризации в новое время послужили публикация листов Letraset с образцами Lorem Ipsum в 60-х годах и, в более недавнее время, программы электронной вёрстки типа Aldus PageMaker, в шаблонах которых используется Lorem Ipsum.
    Lorem Ipsum - это текст-"рыба", часто используемый в печати и вэб-дизайне. Lorem Ipsum является стандартной "рыбой" для текстов на латинице с начала XVI века. В то время некий безымянный печатник создал большую коллекцию размеров и форм шрифтов, используя Lorem Ipsum для распечатки образцов. Lorem Ipsum не только успешно пережил без заметных изменений пять веков, но и перешагнул в электронный дизайн. Его популяризации в новое время послужили публикация листов Letraset с образцами Lorem Ipsum в 60-х годах и, в более недавнее время, программы электронной вёрстки типа Aldus PageMaker, в шаблонах которых используется Lorem Ipsum.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Проще более нормальный CSS написать, мне кажется, чем бороться с этим при помощи JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение с использованием JS:

```js
(function($) {
  $(function() {
    var header = $('.header')
      , sidebar = $('.sidebar');
    $(window).scroll(function() {
      var top = header.height() - $(window).scrollTop();
      sidebar.css('top', top < 0 ? 0 : top);
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #fff;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 10px;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.sidebar {
  width: 140px;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;
  background: pink;
  padding: 10px;
}

.content {
  width: calc(100% - 140px);
  min-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 140px;
  background: blue;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header">HEADER</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="sidebar">SIDEBAR</div>
  <div class="content">
    Lorem Ipsum - это текст-"рыба", часто используемый в печати и вэб-дизайне. Lorem Ipsum является стандартной "рыбой" для текстов на латинице с начала XVI века. В то время некий безымянный печатник создал большую коллекцию размеров и форм шрифтов, используя
    Lorem Ipsum для распечатки образцов. Lorem Ipsum не только успешно пережил без заметных изменений пять веков, но и перешагнул в электронный дизайн. Его популяризации в новое время послужили публикация листов Letraset с образцами Lorem Ipsum в 60-х
    годах и, в более недавнее время, программы электронной вёрстки типа Aldus PageMaker, в шаблонах которых используется Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum - это текст-"рыба", часто используемый в печати и вэб-дизайне. Lorem Ipsum является стандартной "рыбой" для
    текстов на латинице с начала XVI века. В то время некий безымянный печатник создал большую коллекцию размеров и форм шрифтов, используя Lorem Ipsum для распечатки образцов. Lorem Ipsum не только успешно пережил без заметных изменений пять веков, но
    и перешагнул в электронный дизайн. Его популяризации в новое время послужили публикация листов Letraset с образцами Lorem Ipsum в 60-х годах и, в более недавнее время, программы электронной вёрстки типа Aldus PageMaker, в шаблонах которых используется
    Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum - это текст-"рыба", часто используемый в печати и вэб-дизайне. Lorem Ipsum является стандартной "рыбой" для текстов на латинице с начала XVI века. В то время некий безымянный печатник создал большую коллекцию размеров и форм
    шрифтов, используя Lorem Ipsum для распечатки образцов. Lorem Ipsum не только успешно пережил без заметных изменений пять веков, но и перешагнул в электронный дизайн. Его популяризации в новое время послужили публикация листов Letraset с образцами
    Lorem Ipsum в 60-х годах и, в более недавнее время, программы электронной вёрстки типа Aldus PageMaker, в шаблонах которых используется Lorem Ipsum.
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот рабочий код, но он... как и собственно ваш код, нуждается в доработке)))
Вот он - https://jsfiddle.net/jvx5rov6/

```js
$(window).scroll(function () {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() < 70) {
    $('.sidebar').css("top", 70 - $(this).scrollTop() + "px");
  } else {
    $('.sidebar').css("top", "0");
  }
});
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #fff;
}

.header {
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  padding: 10px;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 1000px;
  position: relative;
}

.sidebar {
  top: 70px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 140px;
  position: fixed;
  background: pink;
  padding: 10px;
}

.content {
  width: calc(100% - 160px);
  min-height: 100%;
  margin-left: 160px;
  background: blue;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">HEADER</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="sidebar">SIDEBAR</div>
  <div class="content">
    Lorem Ipsum - это текст-"рыба", часто используемый в печати и вэб-дизайне. Lorem Ipsum является стандартной "рыбой" для текстов на латинице с начала XVI века. В то время некий безымянный печатник создал большую коллекцию размеров и форм шрифтов, используя Lorem Ipsum для распечатки образцов. Lorem Ipsum не только успешно пережил без заметных изменений пять веков, но и перешагнул в электронный дизайн. Его популяризации в новое время послужили публикация листов Letraset с образцами Lorem Ipsum в 60-х годах и, в более недавнее время, программы электронной вёрстки типа Aldus PageMaker, в шаблонах которых используется Lorem Ipsum.
    Lorem Ipsum - это текст-"рыба", часто используемый в печати и вэб-дизайне. Lorem Ipsum является стандартной "рыбой" для текстов на латинице с начала XVI века. В то время некий безымянный печатник создал большую коллекцию размеров и форм шрифтов, используя Lorem Ipsum для распечатки образцов. Lorem Ipsum не только успешно пережил без заметных изменений пять веков, но и перешагнул в электронный дизайн. Его популяризации в новое время послужили публикация листов Letraset с образцами Lorem Ipsum в 60-х годах и, в более недавнее время, программы электронной вёрстки типа Aldus PageMaker, в шаблонах которых используется Lorem Ipsum.
    Lorem Ipsum - это текст-"рыба", часто используемый в печати и вэб-дизайне. Lorem Ipsum является стандартной "рыбой" для текстов на латинице с начала XVI века. В то время некий безымянный печатник создал большую коллекцию размеров и форм шрифтов, используя Lorem Ipsum для распечатки образцов. Lorem Ipsum не только успешно пережил без заметных изменений пять веков, но и перешагнул в электронный дизайн. Его популяризации в новое время послужили публикация листов Letraset с образцами Lorem Ipsum в 60-х годах и, в более недавнее время, программы электронной вёрстки типа Aldus PageMaker, в шаблонах которых используется Lorem Ipsum.
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

собственно, тут без JS никак... Дальше все в ваших руках)))

Comment: У вас высота `.header` элемента захардкожена и `.sidebar` элемент не закеширован, а вычисляется при каждом вызове.

Comment: @Alex Zhulin, для ознакомления подойдет)